I have created a django app and I want to run a function and a view both asynchronous
this is the django view file code.
i have a function which has no parameters and no return since im using global variables in the code.
I am currently using threads and there is an issue. when the startfunc() is running and executing some code, and the data is received at the same time in the view, it just distrupts the startfunc() and the whole process is incomplete which is a big issue for me and the for the app. That's why im trying to use async. if it can be done both of them together( thread + async) i think it would be even more better. let me know if im wrong
i tried async but got this error
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'startfunc' was never awaited
and also showing some errors because of csrf so i added csrf_exempt but still doesnt work
import func # (its a file in the directory of the django app)
global func_running
    

# this is the function

import func # (its a file in the directory of the django app)
global func_running
    
def startfunc():
    while func_running:
        # run a piece of code
        time.sleep(1)


def restview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            raw_data = request.body.decode('utf-8').strip('"')
            data = json.loads(raw_data)
            if "xyz" in data:
                xyz = data["xyz"]
                func.xyz= xyz
                if not func.func_running:
                
                    func_thread = threading.Thread(target=startfunc())
                    func_running = True
                    func_event.set()
                    func_thread.start()
            return Response({"message": "func updated", "func": func})
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return Response({"error": "Invalid JSON"}, status=400)


I want that both functions to run asynchronous. I have tried sync_to_async for the view  function but it was returning errors.

It is not recommended to use global variables in Django, as it actually doesn't really make sense. As explained here, in a production environment you will have multiple instances of the Python process running (in layman terms "multiple terminals running at once") so it does not make sense to talk about global variables. Instead, you should either (1) be using object-oriented Python if the variable is calculated on the fly by user or (2) save in the database.
(1) In particular here django.views.View where you can assign variables within your view class. You can use threads to speed up any loops. For example:
from django.views import Views
from django.http import JsonResponse
import concurrent.futures
import json


class MySpecialView(View):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.result = []
        self.data = json.loads(kwargs["data"])
        self.last_result = 1

    def conditions(self, m):
        return self.last_result % 3 == 0 # Last result is a multiple of 3

    def fun_function(self):
        while self.conditions(self.last_result) is False:
             self.last_result = (self.data[self.last_result])**2 % 4 #this is an example obviously
             self.result.append(self.last_result)
    
    @property
    def context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {"result": self.result}
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun_function()
        return JsonResponse(self.context)

Then make sure in your urls.py you have:
path("/niceurl/<str:data>", views.MySpecialView.as_view())

and where your input data is a string representing a dictionary, e.g., "{0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 9}".
Or in the case of (2) simply save to database using Django's ORM wrapper for SQL.

So, here is the scenario. I have probably 4 or 5 views and json objects is sent to every single view with a different data(e.g., a, b, c, d) and i want to use it in another function. when the task of the function is finished, I dont need the values until the next one comes.
if I use the models to save it. what flow should i use to make that happen?
and when i want to reset it, should i just delete the object?
2nd point is that  how do I change the view into async.
I'm a bit confused about it (and also a noob)

All of the things I'm trying to do is because of a single Issue.
The startfunc() needs to run endlessly until the conditions are met and when  its met, it runs some code which takes like 5-10 secs. sometimes during that a request is received and the code execution is interrupted. I  want to solve that (that's it)

I believe it's a typical Django application here. You can pass either kwargs through your URL or arguments in the request.GET (or POST) dictionary. Editing response now to show you how to do that.
